# Android Logging in eclipse

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I have tried so many things and I can't seem to get a grip on how to use logging correctly I currently want to log a variable but nothing  seems to work can some provide a novice with a dumbed down version please I just want to learn. any help would be appreciated here's my code so far.

```
public void loadLeagueInformation() {

    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
    String gmtTime = df.format(new Date(0)); 

    Log.v(TAG, "TIME:" + gmtTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually from an `Activity` `MyActivity`

```
Log.d("MyActivity", "String date " + gmTime);
```

I'm not sure if you have already formatted `gmTime` to your liking. If not you can use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: how do i filter this i have one set by tag as date is this correct

Comment: You filter by tag in this case "MyActivity". Tag is the first argument of the Log.d

Answer (score 0):

The format is `Log.d(String tag, String msg)`. A common way of doing things is to use the package and/or the class name for `tag`.

For all of my Android classes I do the following (example)...

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
...

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
    ...
}
```

Doing this means that `TAG` will be `com.mycompany.myapp.MyActivity`. If you do this for all Android classes then you are guaranteed that all of the `TAG` fields will start `com.mycompany.myapp` and it's easy to create a filter for logcat to identify all of your 'tags'.

Whenever I need to log something I simply do (example)...

```
Log.d(TAG, "Hello World");
```

Comment: One can use getClass.getSimpleName()

Comment: theres just loads of code showing in the LogCat non of which is the tag i just used exactly same as you

Comment: is there a way to view it in console instead of log cat

Answer (score 0):

In your LogCat window, what is the setting in the drop down box? Is it error? If it was so, then it would show only Logs that are errors i.e. `Log.e(TAG,"..")` Same would apply for the other options.
Since your are using `Log.v(..)` , set it to verbose.

Now, add a filter from the left panel, and enter your tag in the "By Log Tag" field. Select it when you run your application.